# Differentiation under the integral sign for $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan x}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Hello I have a problem that is:

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

I try use the following integral
$$ \int_0^1\frac{dy}{1+x^2y^2}= \frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$$

My question: if I can do $$\frac{\arctan(x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}= \int_0^1\frac{dy}{(1+x^2y^2)(\sqrt{1-x^2})}$$ and solve but I note that the integral is more difficult.

Any comment or any help will be well received.

Thanks.

Comment: Generally$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan ax }{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\frac\pi2\text{arcsinh}\ a$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not to use the Taylor series of $\arctan(x)$?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4n+2}\int_{0}^{1}z^{n-\frac{1}{2}}(1-z)^{-1/2}\,dx $$

by Euler's beta function the LHS is converted into:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(4n+2)\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
and we finally have:

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\text{arcsinh}(1) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\log(1+\sqrt{2})}.$$

An alternative approach is the following one. If we set
$$ I(k)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\arctan(k\sin\theta)}{\sin\theta}\,d\theta $$
our integral is $I(1)$ and $I(0)=0$, while:
$$ I'(k) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+k^2\sin^2\theta} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+k^2}}$$
through the substitution $\theta=\arctan t$. Now $I(1)=\int_{0}^{1}I'(k)\,dk$.

Comment: Thank you, @JackD'Aurizio I do the homework, only that the gamma function I can't be use yet.

Comment: @CamiloAcevedo.: well, my second approach avoids it.

Comment: Ok, @JackD'Aurizio more clever answer thank you I doing this. Is more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
By following the user hint, we'll have:

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\arctan\pars{x} \over x\root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x} & =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y \over 1 + x^{2}y^{2}}}^{\ds{\arctan\pars{x}/x}}\
\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \root{1 - x^{2}}\pars{y^{2}x^{2} + 1}}
\,\dd y
\end{align}

With $x \to 1/x$, the above expression becomes

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\arctan\pars{x} \over x\root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x} & =
\int_{0}^{1}
\int_{1}^{\infty}{x\,\dd x \over \root{x^{2} - 1}\pars{x^{2} + y^{2}}}\,\dd y\
\\[3mm] & \stackrel{x^{2}\ \to\ x}{=}\
\half\int_{0}^{1}
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \root{x - 1}\pars{x + y^{2}}}\,\dd y\
\\[3mm] & \stackrel{x - 1\ \to\ x}{=}\
\half\int_{0}^{1}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \root{x}\pars{x + 1 + y^{2}}}\,\dd y
\\[3mm] & \stackrel{x\ \to\ x^{2}}{=}\
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \root{y^{2} + 1}}\ \overbrace{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}}^{\ds{\pi/2}}\ \,\dd y
\end{align}

With $y \equiv \sinh\pars{\theta}$, the last expression is reduced to

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\arctan\pars{x} \over x\root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x} & =
{\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{\textrm{arcsinh}\pars{1}}\,\dd\theta =
\color{#f00}{{\pi \over 2}\,\textrm{arcsinh}\pars{1} =
             {\pi \over 2}\,\ln\pars{\!\root{2} + 1}} \approx 1.3845
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's star
$$I(y)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(yx)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$ for use the formula above then use differentiation under integral sign and integral methods.